# For google search results in the locale of cakephp

Tags: php, cakephp

It is the internationalization in cakephp.

Create a Chinese (chi) English (eng) to locale under folder,
We've created a po file.

In it has set as follows view.

view.ctp

```
<Table summary = "<php? ​​echo __('company_profile', true);?>">
    <Tr>
        <Th> <php? echo __('company_name', true);?> </ Th>
        <Td> <php? echo __('company_name_value', true);?> </ Td>
    </ Tr>
```

message.po

```
#: \ Views \ sites \ company.ctp: 6
msgid "company_name"
msgstr "Company Name"

#: \ Views \ sites \ company.ctp: 7
msgid "company_name_value"
msgstr "My Company Co.Ltd"
```

There was a problem here.
In google, when you search with "My Company",
'My Company Co.Ltd' rather than, 'company_name_value' has been searched.

[image]

crawler google seems to have been searched for more of msgid.
We want to solve this problem.

Please tell us who know.

Comment: Space is a mistake described.Fixed.

Comment: <tr><th>Company Name</th><td>My Company Co.Ltd</td></tr>